# The usage of 'does'

Tags: word-usage

The passage comes from Medieval Europe by Chris Wickham.

> Peasants do not appear on every page of this book, by any means; but
>   almost everything which ***does*** was paid for by the surplus which they
>   handed over, more or less unwillingly, in rent, and it is a mistake to
>   forget it.

I'd like to ask the voice of '***does***' in this sentence.
My sense of the English grammar makes me wonder if 'does' should not be '***is done***'.
Of course, since its source is from the published book, it is not likely that this word is actually not proper.

But I have two question on the usage of '***does***'.

Frist, doesn't '***is done***' also make sense in the context?

Last, what logic of the grammar makes '***does***' possible and, if you can, can you show another example of this usage?

Comment: No, it's an ellipsis: "but almost everything which does **[appear in the book]** was paid..."

Comment: It hearkens back to the first _do_, of _do not appear in this book_.

Comment: Thanks a lot Laural & John Lawler, I have to look more carefully in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip away anything and everything that *does not* pertain to the basics in this sentence, and you'll see why the word "does" applies (I'm not happy about "which," by the way, I would have used "that" instead, but that's merely a side matter).

> Peasants **do not appear** on every page; but ... almost [**everything** [that] [**does appear on every page of this book**) was [in fact] paid for by [those peasants].